# How do i add a student to the attendance table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to add students to the Attendance Table through the Class_Schedule controller. To do this I created an public ActionResult:

```
public ActionResult Register(int? id)           
{
  if (id == null)
  {
     return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
  Class_Schedule class_Schedule = db.Class_Schedule.Find(id);
  if (class_Schedule == null)
  {
     return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
  //This is the collects the class_schedule ID to make the attendance specific for each class ViewBag.CSid = id;
  ViewBag.studentID = new SelectList(db.Students, "StudentID", "Full_Name");
  ViewBag.instructorID = new SelectList(db.Instructors, "InstructorID", "Name");
  var attendances = db.Attendances;

  return View(attendances.ToList());
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Register([Bind(Include = "AttendanceID,csID,InstructorID,StudentID")] Attendance attendance)
{
  try
  {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      db.Attendances.Add(attendance);
      db.SaveChanges();
      //ViewBag.msg = "Instructor Added";
      return RedirectToAction("Register");
    }
    return View(attendance);
   }
   catch
   {
     return View(attendance);
   }
}
```

This is my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<BBM.Models.Attendance>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}

<h2>Class Schedule @ViewBag.CSid</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register","Class_Schedule", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()


<div class="form-group">
    @{
        var studentid = Model.Select(model => model.StudentID.ToString());
    }
    @Html.Label("StudentID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("StudentID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</div>
<h4>Student register</h4>
<table class="table">
    <tr>

        <th>
            Attendance ID
        </th>
        <th>
            Student ID
        </th>
        <th>
            Student Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Expiry Date
        </th>
    </tr>
    @if (Model != null)
    {

        foreach (var item in Model.Where(p => p.csID.Equals(ViewBag.csID)))
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AttendanceID)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StudentID)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Student.Full_Name)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @if (item.Student.Payments != null && item.Student.Payments.Any(p => p.Expires > DateTime.Now))
                    {
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Student.Payments.OrderByDescending(p => p.paymentID).First(p => p.Expires > DateTime.Now).Expires)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        @Html.DisplayName("Expired");
                    }
                </td>

            </tr>
        }
    }
</table>
     @section Scripts {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
     }
```

This view has a select list to select the students you want to add but but the student ID isn't going into the parameter and the postMethod isn't happening
[image: This is the view as you can see you can select the students but the create or submit buttons don't work]

The ones that are already in there are for test purposes and i did them through the sql server

Answer (score 0):

You have only a specified drop-down id and html attribute. you forgot to pass data to the drop-down helper as you fill in the `ViewBag`. Update as below for student

```
@Html.DropDownList("StudentID",htmlAttributes:new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" },selectList:new SelectList(ViewBag.studentID))
```

Please check that you getting `studentId` on the post method.

Comment: The list is working and the students show, the List is in the controller, but my issue is that the table isn't updating in the view but it is in the MSQLSMS